# mySQL delete query with two condition on separate columns

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I'm using this query to select certain row from the wp_postmeta table

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_postmeta pm
LEFT JOIN wp_posts wp ON wp.ID = pm.meta_value
WHERE (wp.ID IS NULL) AND (pm.meta_key = '_wpcf_belongs_books_id')
```

and it's working fine but when I try to use the DELETE

```
DELETE
FROM wp_postmeta pm
LEFT JOIN fddb_wp_posts wp ON wp.ID = pm.meta_value
WHERE (wp.ID IS NULL) AND (pm.meta_key = '_wpcf_belongs_books_id')
```

it returns an error saying

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'pm LEFT JOIN fddb_wp_posts wp ON wp.ID = pm.meta_value WHERE (wp.ID IS NULL) AND' at line 2

Any suggestion on how to make it work?

Comment: @Strawberry: Deleting records having no relation to another table - seems ok to me. Note the `WHERE wp.ID IS NULL`

Comment: @juergend I guess I'm just used to CASCADE handling that sort of thing.

Comment: Hi @Cheslab I've search before posting but I didn't find anything mentioning the error #1064 ... and since I'm not good at all in mysql it looks like that question was different from mine.

Comment: @carletto0282 Error #1064 just means that MySQL can't understand your command. It's a quite common error. I understand that you may see these questions are different, but for me they are pretty much the same. Eventually you've got the solution for your problem.

Comment: @Cheslab yes I've got the solution and as you can see I confirmed this question is a duplicate. I was just trying to explain why I've created a new question despite the other one. Of course this is a proof I'm a real newbie in mysql... thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a delete statement with more than one table you need to name the tables you want to delete from. Do that right after the `delete` keyword

```
DELETE pm
FROM fddb_wp_postmeta pm ...
```

Comment: Hi @juergen-d that's it! thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE
FROM fddb_wp_postmeta  where 
meta_value not in  (select wp.ID from fddb_wp_posts wp)
  and meta_key = '_wpcf_belongs_books_id'
```

Comment: Hi @vipan-sabherwal thanks... I like very much your suggestion since it let me select rows manually for deleting!